# changing values inside the array in java

Tags: java, eclipse

Good evening
 
i'm trying to solve a question which is :
You are given a int[] marks containing the grades you have received so far in a class. Each
grade is between 0 and 10, inclusive. Assuming that you will receive a 10 on all future
assignments, determine the minimum number of future assignments that are needed for you to
receive a final grade of 10. You will receive a final grade of 10 if your average grade is 9.5 or
higher.

> Definition
>  Class: AimToTen
>  Method: need
>  Parameters:
>   int[]
>  Returns: int
>  Method signature: int need(int[]
>   marks)
>  (be sure your method is public)
>  Examples
>  1)
>   {9, 10, 10, 9}
>  Returns: 0
>  Your average is already 9.5, so no
>   future assignments are needed.
>  2)
>  {8, 9}
>  Returns:
>   4
>  In this case you need 4 more assignments. With each
>   completed
>  assignment, your average could increase to 9, 9.25, 9.4
>   and 9.5, respectively

My attempt to solve is :

```
public int need(int[] marks) {
    int i=0, sum = 0, avg = 0, k = 0, counter = 0, ToCompleteMarks[] = null;
    for (i; i < marks.length; i++) {

        sum = sum + marks[i];
        ToCompleteMarks[i] = marks[i] + ToCompleteMarks[i];// To copy the array so when i add 10 later to the program the original array does not change > good ?
    }
    avg = sum / marks.length;


    while (avg < 9.5)
        ToCompleteMarks[i]; //I need to add the number 10 to the array then get back to calculate the avg . But no ideas how to do that ! .
        counter++;

    return counter;

}
```

if you could help me with that I would be really greatful

thanks

Comment: What problem are you having?  I mean, other than that you haven't actually even written a `main` which calls any of your code.

Comment: I do not really need a main . It's just a method to pass the values in

Comment: I'm trying to explain my issue inside as a comment

Comment: Guessing and checking is all fine and good, but you can probably solve this problem pretty simply with basic algebra

Comment: @SamIam I did not a way to add the integer 10 to the array then go back to calculate the avg . This is actually my problem

Comment: `(sum + 10*x)/(marks.length + x) >= 9.5)`  solve for `x`

Comment: @Scatteril are you sure that you're supposed to add items to the array?  Arrays don't support random insertion

Comment: and does your code not throw a null reference exception?

Comment: @SamIam thanks for reminding me to add the value 10 to the sum not the array . I wish you best of luck with a wonderful future . I got it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do the below mentioned steps:
1. Get the difference between the avg calculated and the desired average(9.5)
LEts say that the calculated average is 8.
Difference would be 9.5-8 = 1.5
Hence we can take the upper limit(ceiling value) of the difference using Math.ceil(difference). Here it would be 2. Thus we need to add two assignments to the array.

Comment: I thought about it and it seems to be more complex than it could . There are a different ways to solve as I saw .
Thanks for your interest